# What is the best way in Python to detect objects' ID being clicked with mouse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I would like to ask what is the best way in Python to interact with a canvas objects which were created with function.
My example code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=600, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

def rectangle(x, y):
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 5, y + 5, fill="white")

rect1 = rectangle(20, 50)
rect2 = rectangle(180, 30)
rect3 = rectangle(698, 322)
rect4 = rectangle(900, 66)
rect5 = rectangle(10, 506)
rect6 = rectangle(208, 455)
```

What is the best way to detect ID of the object which is being clicked with a mouse and then use those IDs as arguments in another function? Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You can use `canvas.find_withtag("current")` to get the item ID of the canvas object being clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tag_bind`.

```
import tkinter
from functools import partial

window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=600, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

def on_click(item, event=None):
    print(f"Item id {item} was clicked!")

def rectangle(x, y):
    item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 5, y + 5, fill="white")
    canvas.tag_bind(item_id, '<Button-1>', partial(on_click, item_id))

rect1 = rectangle(20, 50)
rect2 = rectangle(180, 30)
rect3 = rectangle(698, 322)
rect4 = rectangle(900, 66)
rect5 = rectangle(10, 506)
rect6 = rectangle(208, 455)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however I had in mind if it is possible to get those IDs like `rect1`, `rect2` etc. as a value of a string variable (and eventually print them or use them somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @bilykralik16 for that, a way could be to store the variables `rect1`, etc. into a list and then access them using indices, if you do not plan on actually using these objects in the future, then you might as well just store a string corresponding to each.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas has a method named `find_closest` which will return the object nearest the cursor.

```
def highlight_nearest(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    item = canvas.find_closest(x, y)
    canvas.itemconfigure(item, fill="red")

canvas.bind("<1>", highlight_nearest)
```

The `find_closest` method takes an x and y coordinate, and an optional `halo` and `start` argument.

This is what [the official documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M24)  has to say:

> Selects the item closest to the point given by *x* and *y*. If more than one item is at the same closest distance (e.g. two items overlap the point), then the top-most of these items (the last one in the display list) is used. If *halo* is specified, then it must be a non-negative value. Any item closer than halo to the point is considered to overlap it. The *start* argument may be used to step circularly through all the closest items. If *start* is specified, it names an item using a tag or id (if by tag, it selects the first item in the display list with the given tag). Instead of selecting the topmost closest item, this form will select the topmost closest item that is below *start* in the display list; if no such item exists, then the selection behaves as if the *start* argument had not been specified.